# Linked List clear function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to clear a linked list at the end of a program using this function clearList but i dont know exactly what is wrong with this definition of the funtion.

```
void clearList(struct node *list) { 
    struct node *p; 
    for(p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        free(p);
}
```

Comment: if you free the node you can not go to the next one. There are many examples on the internet

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the *next* pointer before you free the node:

```
p = list; //list is the header

while( p != NULL ){
    list = list->next;

    free(p);

    p = list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `free` on your `Node` object before you have a copy of the address in `next`.  This will trap that memory and cause a memory leak.  Even worse you are trying to reference memory that has already been freed which will segfault your program.

Create a copyof `next` first:

```
struct node *p, *nxt;
for (p=list; p; p=nxt) {
    nxt = p->next;
    free(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With list I recommend tail recursive function:

```
void free_list(struct node *head) {
  if (head != NULL) {
    struct node *next = head->next;
    free(head);
    free_list(next);
  }
}
```

Comment: In a real-world scenario, you can do this in an iterative manner much more efficiently. If you're working with a massive list, your implementation wastes a lot of CPU cycles in overhead due to context switching, and you run the risk of overflowing the call stack.

Comment: @DevNull You wrong, I say it's a tail recursive function. A good compiler will optimize it. Why do you look all my answer just because I critique one of yours?

Comment: You're relying on a compiler optimization to accommodate poor coding practices. A lot of embedded systems utilize custom compilers other than GCC, and this will fail both unit tests and LINT.

Comment: @DevNull Sorry, but my answer is correct. "In a real-world scenario", people use gcc or clang and it's perform this optimization. Don't downvote my answer, just because you think that functional programing is bad. I hope that people who write embedded systems know what there doing.

Comment: @DevNull In a real embedded programming world, people tend to use GCC/clang as they provide compiling tools for a lot of different platforms with a lot of optimization for all of them (as they generally operate on an IR of the compiled program)
That said, the tail-recursion optimization is a "common" optimization that all modern compilers (which I *hope* people use) do, there is some cases where it can't do this optimization, but a simple one as terminating with a recursion is almost always done, and then you can safely assume that it *will* be done